# Default reviewers gitlab

Tags: gitlab, devops

Long story short: I have a subgroup that contains 100 project, I want to assign default MR reviewers for this subgrouo so it can apply on all the projects there!
Is there any hacky way to do it? Gitlab doesnt offer the possibility to configure this per-subgroup level.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A *hacky* way might be to create a job in the MR pipeline to do this using a [project access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html) or [group access token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/group/settings/group_access_tokens.html) with API read/write scope.

Example using [python-gitlab](https://python-gitlab.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html)'s CLI.

First, create a group access token and set it on the subgroup CI/CD variables settings as `GROUP_ACCESS_TOKEN`.

Then also set a `REVIEWER_IDS` variable on the subgroup with the user IDs of the default reviewers.

```yaml
assign-mr:
  stage: .post  # use .post to avoid getting in the way of other jobs
  needs: []  # start immediately
  variables:
    # set these variables at the subgroup level settings:
    # User IDs of the reviewers you want to add to the MR
    # REVIEWER_IDS: "1,2,3"
    # set this as a masked variable at the subgroup settings:
    # GROUP_ACCESS_TOKEN: <secret!>

    GIT_STRATEGY: none  # skip checkout
    GITLAB_URL: "$CI_SERVER_URL"  # used by python-gitlab
    GITLAB_PRIVATE_TOKEN: "$GROUP_ACCESS_TOKEN" # used by python-gitlab

  image:
    name: registry.gitlab.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab:latest
    entrypoint: [""]
  rules:
    - if '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request"'
  script: |
    if [[ -f ".done" ]]; then
        echo "Already successfully updated MR. Skipping!" > /dev/stderr
        exit 0
    fi
    gitlab project-merge-request update \
      --project-id "$CI_PROJECT_ID" \
      --iid "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID" \
      --reviewer-ids "$REVIEWER_IDS" \
   && \
   touch .done  # marker to know if we successfully updated the MR

  cache: # use a cache so we only update the MR once (allowing changes afterwards)
    key: "$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_IID"
    paths:
      - .done
```

Comment: That looks quite useful but im actually using jenkins pipeline!

Comment: @Oussema the same principle is applicable with Jenkins. At the end of the day, it's just making HTTP requests to GitLab with a token.

Comment: okay but let's say I have a subgroup with 100 projects inside and 100 pipelines. Do I need to put this in every pipeline there?